# Possible to Generate Multiple Similar Infopath Forms Based on Filled Out Template?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, infopath

We have a sharepoint infopath form that regularly has to go to multiple groups with each verifying and signing off their own copy of the form. These forms are completely identical other that the "Group" selected in a drop-down. We are currently manually going in and remaking each of these forms and selecting the same boxes, filling in same info etc.

Is there a way, via workflow or some other method, that if we had a multiple choice for the "Groups" we could have multiple forms generated automatically with each assigned to one of the groups selected in the multiple choice?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned

> These forms are completely identical other that the "Group" selected
> in a drop-down

One option I think may be helpful will be using the rules.

I made a demo to add a button to the form, then manage the rules on that button. I add multiple submit data actions to it. Before each submission, I changed the value of a certain field, then use the submit action to send the form to different SharePoint libraries. When clicking the button, the forms will be sent to all of the libraries with the varied field values I set.

As I am not sure the way you want to handle the form so you may spend some time on setting the submission data connection, however it seems to be a good approach in my test.

A reference for you:https://support.formotus.com/hc/en-us/articles/201042497-How-to-configure-a-multiple-submit-in-InfoPath

https://redcapeco.com/create-submit-button-infopath-form-email-recipients/ (It is in InfoPath 2010 but the logic is identical for InfoPath 2013)